# How to add a password and output directory using Zipfile module in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got below code from online and I am trying to add a password and I want to change the result directory to be  "C:#SFTPDWN" (Final Zip file should be in this folder).

I try to change it like below, it did not work.

```
with ZipFile('CC-Data.zip', 'w', 'pass word') as zip:
```

Can anybody please tell how to change this code to add password and change result folder?

One last thing, currently it will zip #SFTPDWN folder, I just want to zip everything inside (Right now it will create two folders (CC-Data.zip and inside it #SFTPDWN )). Can anybody please tell me how to zip everything inside #SFTPDWN folder?

Code

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os


def get_all_file_paths(directory):
    file_paths = []

    for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            file_paths.append(filepath)

    return file_paths


def main():
    # path to folder which needs to be zipped
    directory = 'C:\#SFTPDWN'

    file_paths = get_all_file_paths(directory)

    print('Following files will be zipped:')
    for file_name in file_paths:
        print(file_name)

    with ZipFile('CC-Data.zip', 'w') as zip:
        # writing each file one by one
        for file in file_paths:
            zip.write(file)

    print('Zipped successfully!')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the password question: from the documentation:

> This module [...] supports decryption of encrypted files in ZIP archives, **but it currently cannot create an encrypted file**. Decryption is extremely slow as it is implemented in native Python rather than C.
>
> - https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html

You would need to use a 3rd party library to create an encrypted zip, or encrypt the archive some other way.

For the second part, in `ZipFile.write` the documentation also mentions:

> `ZipFile.write(filename, arcname=None, compress_type=None, compresslevel=None)`
>
> Write the file named `filename` to the archive, **giving it the archive name `arcname`** (by default, this will be the same as `filename`, but without a drive letter and with leading path separators removed). [...]
>
> Note: Archive names should be relative to the archive root, that is, they should not start with a path separator.
>
> - https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write

So you would need to strip off whatever prefix of your `file` variable and pass that as the `arcname` parameter. Using [`os.path.relpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath) may help, e.g. (I'm on Linux, but should work with Windows paths under Windows):

```
>>> os.path.relpath("/folder/subpath/myfile.txt", "/folder/")
'subpath/myfile.txt'
```

Sidebar: a path like `"C:\Something"` is an illegal string, as it has the escape `\S`. Python kinda tolerates this (I think in 3.8 it will error) and rewrites them literally. Either use `"C:\\Something"`, `r"C:\Something"`, or `"C:/Something"` If you attempted something like `"C:\Users"` it would actually throw an error, or `"C:\nothing"` it might silently do something strange...

Comment: Thank you so much for details explanation. I appreciate your time and help.